# Convert sql results to 'select UNION select' query (exportable data)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, converters

Sometimes we need to debug with our client data and we dont have time to take a complete database backup so we convert manually a sql result to a combination of static 'select UNION select UNION' so we can use their data on the fly...

Example:

```
select * from items
```

Results:

```
Itemcode     ItemName     Price
Car1         FerrariX     1200.00
Car2         FerrariZ     3000.00
Car3         MustangR     2100.00
```

And we bring it back to our debuging enviroment like this:

```
select 'Car1' as Itemcode, 'FerrariX' as Itemname, 1200.00 as 'Price' UNION
select 'Car2',             'FerrariZ', 3000.00 UNION
select 'Car3',             'MustangR', 2100.00
```

Posible Stored Procedure Solution:

```
EXEC spQueryAsStaticData @Query = 'select * from items'
```

How can we do this transformation automatically? Some stored procedure?

Comment: Let me guess. Your possible SP solution in your post, just tells us how you want to call the SP spQueryAsStaticData. Can you post the code of that SP here, unless you are expecting someone to code that SP for you?

Comment: @MahmoudGamal it could be 2005 or superior...it will depend on the client... and the VALUES function doesnt seem to be the solution i need. (Maybe i can explain better the question?)

Comment: @Raj I dont have the code as its an idea of one possible solution that i dont know how to develop. But if someone knows it or has an alternative solution it will be gladly accepted ^^

Comment: Why can you not use the built in script table function, with schema+data enabled?

Comment: @Raj becouse normally it will be complex querys with joins and conditions, in the example i did a simple query for clarity...

Comment: You might find it easier to buy  a tool like AdeptSQL Diff to create data generation scripts. It's also great for creation inserts, updates, deletes against two tables.

Comment: So, you are saying that you will run a complex query with multiple joins and conditions and then you need the result set to be converted to "Select UNION Select" statement, right?

Comment: @Raj thats it exactly ^^

Comment: @Raj Thats why i thought a stored procedure that does this would be the best solution (or a begin end code block executed directly in their database without creating the stored procedure, for cleanliness)

Answer (score 0):

i use something like this to print out text using data

```
DECLARE @i int
DECLARE @employee_id int
Declare @Hash nvarchar(max)
declare @Result nvarchar(max)
Declare @String nvarchar(MAX)
DECLARE @numrows int
DECLARE @employee_table TABLE (
    idx smallint Primary Key IDENTITY(1,1)
    , [ID] int , [Hash] nvarchar(50), Result nvarchar(50)
)


INSERT @employee_table
SELECT Top 5 * FROM [Hlist].[dbo].[MD5]
set @i =0 
set @String = '' 


SET @numrows = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @employee_table)

IF @numrows > 0

    WHILE (@i <= (SELECT MAX(idx) FROM @employee_table))
    BEGIN


        -- get the next employee primary key
        SET @employee_id = (SELECT ID  FROM @employee_table WHERE idx = @i)
        SET @Hash = (SELECT Hash  FROM @employee_table WHERE idx = @i)
        SET @Result = (SELECT Result  FROM @employee_table WHERE idx = @i)
        Set @String = coalesce(@String +'Select '+ convert(varchar,@employee_id) + ', ' +@Hash+ ', '+@Result +' Union ', '')

        --
        -- do something with this employee
        --


        -- increment counter for next employee
        SET @i = @i + 1
    END


    Print @String
```

Comment: Thanks but its not applicable in our case, being our query dynamic and an input parameter we would need to loop thought the query resulting columns (loop cursor resultset columns/fields)...and we havent found a way of doing it... :S

Answer (score 0):

In the end we solved it developing a little C# app, not as useful as generating it directly from a SQL query but it works...

If someone gives the SQL solution we will grant the answer to him/her